# AWS - Cannot connect via SSH - I Get "Permission denied (publickey)"

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ssh-keys

I just created and Ubuntu instance on `Amazon AWS`.

On their instructions to connect via SSH (they offer you instructions with your own paramters), they say:

```
To access your instance:
Open an SSH client. (find out how to connect using PuTTY)
Locate your private key file (my.experiments.com.pem). The wizard automatically detects the key you used to launch the instance.
Your key must not be publicly viewable for SSH to work. Use this command if needed:
chmod 400 my.experiments.com.pem
Connect to your instance using its Public DNS:
ec2-13-58-23-167.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com

Example:
ssh -i "my.experiments.com.pem" ubuntu@ec2-13-58-23-167.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

Then, I do:

```
$ ssh -vvv -i "my.experiments.com.pem" ubuntu@ec2-13-58-23-167.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

and then I get:

```
debug2: resolving "ec2-13-58-23-167.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-13-58-23-167.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com [13.58.23.167] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file my.experiments.com.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file my.experiments.com.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.2 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-13-58-23-167.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ubuntu'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/George/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/George/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-13-58-23-167.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:8iA/gquNIyDIY9t1CjUTP1GrkEcZs24QZr8LB2v4aEQ
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/George/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/George/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-13-58-23-167.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/George/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/George/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 13.58.23.167
debug1: Host 'ec2-13-58-23-167.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/George/.ssh/known_hosts:3
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: my.experiments.com.pem (0x0), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: my.experiments.com.pem
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:liwduQln1POAMqbxk05dlG2yYLzGCmb4gTK3ERUYOJs
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I did what they recommend:

```
$ chmod 400 my.experiments.com.pem
```

I also tried to connect with `Putty` converting the file: `my.experiments.com.pem` to `my.experiments.com.ppk` (Putty private key) with `puttygen.exe` but no success. With Putty, when trying to connect I get: `Disconnected: No supported authentication methods available (server sent: publickey)` in an error popup window.

**[EDIT 1]**

As you can see on the following image, the instance was launched with the key pair: `aws.playmeetup.com`. As suggested on:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectingMindTerm

Where it says: Confirm that you are using the private key file that corresponds to the key pair that you selected when you launched the instance.

[image]

Comment: So your workstation is windows?

Comment: it is an Ubuntu instance there en AWS. That's why they give me the above connection user: `ubuntu` to connect via `SSH`.

Comment: @davidesp but what about your workstation? I mean, from what OS you are trying to connect to the EC2 instance?

Comment: oh, I'm using Windows 10. I tried connecting from `cygwin` console and from `Putty`

Comment: @davidesp When you created the EC2 instance are you sure you specified to boot it with the same key that you are trying to use to connect to it? Just checking the basics (but often missed) here ;)

Comment: yes I did. Please, check the `[EDIT 1]` on my question above.

Comment: @davidesp When you do `cat "my.experiments.com.pem"` just before execute the `ssh` all is good? I mean, the file content is printed on the screen? The other thing is that I noticed that the names of your local private key file and the key you selected on EC2 aren't the same, pls, make sure that you are using the private key of the same pair key you selected up there.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing:

`$ ssh -vvv -i "my.experiments.com" ubuntu@ec2-13-58-23-167.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

when should be:

`$ ssh -vvv -i "my.experiments.com.pem" ubuntu@ec2-13-58-23-167.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com`

Comment: I did a mistake when posting the question here in StackOverflow (just that). I fixed the question above.

Answer (score 0):

All anyone can do is make a guess, so here's mine:

Your screenshot shows the name of the key pair was, aws.playmeetup.com, and yet you have stated several times that the key you are trying to use is my.experiments.com.pem.

That is not the correct key.